# MapStruct - Cannot find implementation with IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, mapstruct, mapper

Using latest Springboot MapStruct 1.3.1 version to convert Dtos into an object. (Java 11, Gradle 6.6 version)
I'm getting the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
   Error creating bean with name 'userController' defined in 
   file [/directory/UserController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed 
   through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
   Error creating bean with name 'userServiceImpl' defined in 
   file [/directory/UserServiceImpl.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; 
   nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
  Failed to instantiate [package.service.UserServiceImpl]: 
  Constructor threw exception; 
  nested exception is 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  Cannot find implementation for package.service.mapper.UserMapper
```

Please could you take a look where I'm going wrong?

My code:

build.gradle

```
    compile group: 'org.mapstruct', name: 'mapstruct', version: '1.3.1.Final'
```

UserController.java

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3306)
@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    private final UserServiceImpl userService;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> login(UserDTO request) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.login(request));
    }
```

UserService.java

```
public interface UserService {
    public UserDTO login(UserDTO user);
}
```

UserServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserServiceImpl extends CheckException implements UserService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private UserMapper mapper = Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);

    @Override
    public UserDTO login(UserDTO user) {
        usernameParameterCheck(user.getId());
        User currentUser = userRepository.findUserByIdAndPassword(user.getId(), user.getPassword());
        userNullCheck(currentUser);
        return mapper.entityToDto(currentUser);
    }
}
```

UserMapper.java

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper {
    User dtoToEntity(UserDTO userDTO);
    UserDTO entityToDto(User user);
}
```

Comment: you also need to configure the processing for MapStruct just adding the dependency isn't enough. Also you should inject the mapper not obtain it manually. Not related but it will become an issue, your controller should reference the `UserService` (the interface) and not the actual implementation `UserServiceImpl`.

Comment: Thank you! I add the dependency 'MapStruct-processor' and edit the reference. How should I inject the mapper in manually?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fix this: add '@NoArgsConstructor' annotation in DTO class :D

Comment: This is not a proper solution. You should upgrade to the latest version of MapStruct (1.4.1.Final at this moment) and use the constructor mapping feature.

Comment: My company use 1.3.1 Final version. So I have to work on that version. When company upgrade to the latest version I'll follow your comment Thank you!